# Working with non-static Spinner in static class

Tags: android, static, non-static

I am trying to make this:

1. In DatePickerDialog user set a date
2. Date will be written in Spinner

The problem is that DatePickerFragment class which includes OnDateSet method is static and the spinner is non-static. In OnDateSet method I need to add item to adapter and call method Spinner.setSelection(int i)

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year1, int month1, int day1) {
    firstdate = day1 + "/" + month1 + "/" + year1;
    addapter.add(firstdate);
    Spinner.setSelection(1);
}
```

Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance!
Filip

Comment: How are you instantiating `DatePickerDialog`?  Please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

whole class:

```
 public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

           @Override
           public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
               final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
               int year1 = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)-25;
               int month1 = 0;
               int day1 = 1;


               // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
               return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year1, month1, day1);
           }

           public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year1, int month1, int day1) {
               firstdate = day1 + "/" + month1 + "/" + year1;
           }

       }
```